# Create class which components can take only values from the set {0, 1 , 2}

Tags: c#

How to create a collection, array which values are only 0 , 1 , 2 numbers.
I have a task to create an mathematical vector, which components are only from the set {0 ,1 ,2}. So I need some data structure which can contain only 0 ,1 ,2 values and nothing else. How to implement such a set or impose restrictions on class field? Helpe me please.`

```
public class MyClass
{
// This type supposed to contains only values from the set {0 ,1 , 2}.
    Type components;
}
```

Comment: Use an enumeration

Comment: Charles Bretana, But as I know, enumeration contains only string values.Am i right?

Comment: @What nope, the underlying data is numeric. Identifiers in code are for the ease of use.

Comment: Ok, i got it.Thank you.

Comment: Must those values be enforced at compile time, or is runtime good enough?

Comment: Use a [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an enumeration:

```
enum JustZeroOneTwo {
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

You can even use the underlying integers instead of the identifiers:

```
public MyClass(int zeroonetwo) {
    components = zeroonetwo;
}
```

Note that using this, you have to manually check whether the number is in your set. Directly passing a value of type `JustZeroOneTwo` eliminates this boundary check:

```
public MyClass(JustZeroOneTwo jzot) {
    components = jzot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here..

```
public enum MyClassDomain{One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3}

public class MyClass
{
    private MyClassDomain intVal { get; set;)
    private MyClass() {}
    public static MyClass Make(int value) // <--- Factory to create instance
    { return new MyClass {Component = value}; }
    public int Component
    { 
        get { return (int) intval; }
        [private] set    //  <-- make this prIvate to make immutable
        {
            if(value < 1 || value > 3) 
                 throw new ArgumentException
                    ("Value out of range.");
            intVal = (MyClassDomain) value;
        }
}
```